# Understanding time complexity for python code

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm completely new to time complexity problems. I'm writing Python code for a Codility exercise and the code I've written returns time out error with a time complexity of O(N*N). The expected time complexity is O(N).

Given a list of integers `A`,
I'm trying to compute the minimum difference between the sum of `A[0:i]` and the sum of `A[i:]`, for all index `i` in `A`.

Here's my solution:

```
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 2.7
    a=[]
    for i in range(1,len(A)):
        a.append(abs(sum(A[0:i])-sum(A[i:len(A)+1])))
    return min(a)
```

I tried to improve the code by implementing the following

```
import sys
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 2.7
    a=sys.maxint
    for i in range(1,len(A)):
        temp=abs(sum(A[0:i])-sum(A[i:len(A)+1]))
        if temp<a:
            a=temp
    return a
```

I still get the same complexity. I understand the `abs` step is taking a lot of time to compute. How do I reduce time complexity for this code? Is there an intuitive way of looking at time complexity problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of the loop,
you recalculate the sum of elements up to index `i`,
and the sum of elements after index `i`.
This is inefficient,
because you can accumulate the sum as you go.

```
suffix = sum(A)
prefix = 0
mindiff = suffix

for a in A:
    prefix += a
    suffix -= a
    mindiff = min(mindiff, abs(prefix - suffix))

return mindiff
```

There were other issues too with your code:

- There's no need to make a list of the differences. You can track the minimum value (as I did)
- The end index in `A[i:len(A)+1]` is beyond the range of `A`, which is confusing to read, and it suggests that you might be confused about list indexing in Python. This should have been `A[i:len(A)]`, or even better, simply `A[i:]`.

> Is there an intuitive way of looking at time complexity problems?

Absolutely.
The intuition here is that to calculate the sum of a range of values,
you need to iterate over them.
So that's `O(N)` right there.
If this is within another `O(N)` loop,
then the overall complexity becomes `O(N*N)`.
Your mistake was overlooking the cost of summing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Any books that you would recommend to understand time complexity?

Comment: @Misha I this one excellent, see the PDF link near the top of the page. https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/ I also recommend to complete the exercises on this page. In fact all the lessons here are brilliant, and all aspiring programmers should go through them.